# jQuery Adicionar classe a elemento gerado dinamicamente com click, porém apenas em um deles e ao clicar em outro, remover dos demais elementos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

Olá, boa noite amigos, tudo bom? Estou estudando e desenvolvendo uma Todo list,após adicionar um item(`<li>`) a minha `<ol>`, criei um eventListener para que ao clicar em um dos items da lista, esse receba a classe `.selected`, porém, todos os itens recebem a classe, não apenas o clicado, o pior, é que como travei nisso, não estou conseguindo prosseguir pra implementar a continuação, quer seria ao clicar em outro item, ele receber a classe `.selected` enquanto o último clicado a perderia.

Como sou novo na programação e principalmente em jQuery, estou batendo cabeça aqui tentando entender como seria o funcionamento para alcançar o resultado desejado, alguém poderia me dar um luz por gentileza?

JsFiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/ruqwgeh2/

Js:

```
// ADICIONA UM NOVO ITEM
$("#criar-tarefa").click(function () {
  if ($("#texto-tarefa").val() === "") {
    alert("Você deve digitar algo para ser adicionado a lista!");
  } else {
    $("#lista-tarefas").append(
      `<li class="item-lista">${$("#texto-tarefa").val()}</li>`
    );
    $("#texto-tarefa").val("");
  }
});

$("#lista-tarefas").on("click", "li", function () {
  $("li").addClass("selected");
});

// REMOVE OS FINALIZADOS
$("#remover-finalizados").click(function () {
  $(".completed").remove();
});

// TODO: SALVAR TAREFAS WEBSTORAGE
// $('#salvar-tarefas').click(function () {
// });

// REMOVE OS SELECIONADOS
$("#remover-selecionado").click(function () {
  $(".selected").remove();
});

// APAGA TUDO
$("#apaga-tudo").click(function () {
  $("#lista-tarefas").empty();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fala Arthur, tudo bem...

Vamos analisar seu código:

```
$("#lista-tarefas").on("click", "li", function () {
  $("li").addClass("selected");
});
```

Esse trecho do código quer dizer o seguinte: Selecione todos os elementos **li** que são filhos do ID **lista-tarefas** e ouça o **evento** de **click** de cada um e quando um desses elementos for clicado, adicione a classe **selected** em todos os elementos **li**.

Então o código está fazendo exatamente isso, sempre quando você clicar em um elemento **li** ele vai adicionar a classe **selected** em todos os **li** da página.

Vamos mudar a primeira premissa para o seguinte: Ouça o evento de clique de todos os elementos **li** que esteja dentro do elemento que possui o ID **lista-tarefa** e quando um deles for clicado, adicione a classe **selected** apenas no item que foi clicado.
Então temos o seguinte:

```
$("#lista-tarefas").on("click", "li", function (e) {
  $(e.target).addClass("selected");
});
```

A função que está sendo passada como terceiro parâmetro é uma callback e ela recebe um parâmetro, um objeto que possui informações sobre o evento disparado. Uma dessas informações é o **target** (alvo) ou seja, o elemento que ao ser clicado disparou a função.

Você pode aprender mais sobre o **click event** neste link sobre a sua API no site da Mozilla [clicando aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event).

Então neste caso um dos seus problemas está resolvido.

O próximo é o seguinte: Você gostaria de que todos os outros elementos **li** exceto o clicado tenha a classe **selected** removida.

Então antes de atribuirmos a classe **selected** ao **li** clicado, podemos remover a classe de todos os elementos que a possui.

Por exemplo:

```
  $('.selected').removeClass("selected");
```

Então a solução completa seria assim:

```
$("#lista-tarefas").on("click", "li", function (e) {
  $('.selected').removeClass("selected");
  $(e.target).addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: Caramba Rafael, muito obrigado pela ajuda e parabéns pela didática, de verdade, eu cheguei a tentar algo como function (event), mas não tinha dado por que não conhecia o .targer, consegui entender! Principalmente pela forma como você explicou, foi a primeira vez que usei o stack overflow e fiquei bastante surpreso, enfim, muito obrigado!!!!

Comment: @ArthurNunes, fico feliz em te ajudar cara, quando puder ajude alguém também. Abraço!